# Literature request: Resonances of (Schrödinger) operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, book-recommendation

Can anyone provide accepted literature, preferably textbooks, which introduce the concept of resonances of (Schrödinger) operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preface and introduction of the new book ["Mathematical theory of scattering resonances"](http://math.mit.edu/~dyatlov/res/res_final.pdf), by Semyon Dyatlov and Maciej Zworski, should already help get an idea.